# PHP echo and download pdf headers

Tags: php, header, http-headers

Im in a situation where users can click a download button in a pop up.  When they click "download", a request is made to my php script.  The php script generates the PDF, echoes a script tag to close the modal and then downloads the PDF.  I dont want to do a setTimeout to close the modal because of the timing differences for the PDF to be generated, which is why im echoing the script tag to close the modal.  I've tried using ob_start/ob_end_flush but it still wont work. help! Thanks :)

The file gets downloaded, but the script tags wont get echoed.  If I comment out the header & readfile, the script tags get echoed, so I know its just because output stops or something.

```
ob_start();
echo('<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>');
echo('<script>jQuery("body", window.parent.document).find("#pdfModal").addClass("out").removeClass("in")</script>');
header("Content-type:application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename='results.pdf'");
readfile('../wp-content/plugins/ajaxpostfromfront/' . $token . '/results.pdf');
ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: Lol someone really down voted this?

Comment: I would echo the modal closing and redirect to the pdf download.